# BlockingCollection OperationCancelledException

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

We've got this piece of code at work where we read from a `BlockingCollection` in a background thread to report progress. Occasionally the line

```
foreach (int i in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
```

will throw an `OperationCancelledException`. This seems unusual as there isn't a cancellation token in sight. In fact I'd be expecting an `ObjectDisposedException` instead as mentioned in the documentation of the `GetConsmingEnumerable` method. Does anyone know what is happening? It only happens occasionally.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Process()
    {
        var collection = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<int>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (int i in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine(i); // simulate reporting progress
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        var input = Enumerable.Range(1, 100); // simulate list of items to do work on

        Parallel.ForEach(input, i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Simulate doing work

            collection.Add(i);                
        });

        collection.CompleteAdding();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs).

Comment: I did and it appears the `OperationCancelledException` is only thrown if cancellation is requested, which it isn't.

Comment: Obviously something is doing the cancellation even though it is not cooperative from your point of view. Investigate OperationCancelledException object especially cancellation token to try to get to the source.